# Scala implicit string conversions utility

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write some string utils to be able to do implicit conversions of the form `"myString".doSpecialConversion` and have a `specialValue` based on which `doSpecialConversion` works.

**Attempt-1:** Use a trait:

```
trait ConversionUtils {

  // Need an overridable value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  lazy val specialValue = ","

  implicit class StringConversions(val s: String) {
    def doSpecialConversion: Option[String] = if (s == specialValue) None else Some(s)
  }
}
```

Trait works just fine but the problem is that its not static so multiple `StringConversions` will be created which is undesired. So I try to extend `AnyVal` which can't be done for a trait because [`Another limitation that is a result of supporting only one parameter to a class is that a value class must be top-level or a member of a statically accessible object.`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)

**Attempt-2:** Use a singleton:

```
object ConversionUtils {

  // Need an overridable value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  lazy val specialValue = ","

  implicit class StringConversions(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
    def doSpecialConversion: Option[String] = if (s == specialValue) None else Some(s)
  }
}
```

**Question**: How do I provide a Util to be able to override the specialValue for StringConversions and be true-ly static?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for an implicit parameter:

```
object ConversionUtils {

  case class SpecialValue(str: String)

  implicit class StringConversions(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
    def doSpecialConversion(implicit sv: SpecialValue): Option[String] = if (s == sv.str) None else Some(s)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> implicit val sp = SpecialValue(",")
sp: ConversionUtils.SpecialValue = SpecialValue(,)

scala> "aaa".doSpecialConversion
res0: Option[String] = Some(aaa)

scala> ",".doSpecialConversion
res1: Option[String] = None
```

In general case, macro-libraries, like [machinist](https://github.com/typelevel/machinist) might help to get rid of boilerplate.